# Validation Rule Hook For WooCommerce Order Action

Tags: validation, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm adding a custom WooCommerce Action to my edit order pages, but I can't seem to figure out how to run validations.

For instance:

- I want to send an email when my action runs, only if a certain condition is met.
- When the validation fails, I want to indicate a wp-admin notice; this is where I'm stuck....it keeps only outputting 'Order Updated'

What I have:

- The custom action in the select box in my edit order view The ability
  to run actions when the custom action is selected

Where I'm stuck:

- Outputting some kind of alert in wp-admin when validation conditions
  fail for my custom action

My Code

```
// Adds the action
function add_custom_order_actions($actions, $order) {
    $actions['customAction'] = __( 'Custom Action', 'namespace' );
    return $actions;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_actions', 10, 2);

// Custom action handling
function order_action_customAction($order) {


    if (
        // Validation is false
    ) {
        // Output an alert in wp-admin
        add_action('admin_notices', function () {
            echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>Validation error</p></div>';
        });

        // Stop the order action from being processed
        return false;
    }

    // Do stuff if valid

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_customAction', 'order_action_customAction' );
```